# Does MSVC10 Visual Studio 2010 support C++ explicit conversion operators

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, c++11

Does Visual Studio 2010 MSVC10 support explicit conversion operators, or is the safe bool idiom still required to be implemented?

This code does not compile:

```
  explicit operator bool() const
  {
    return Traits::invalid() != value;
  }
```

Compiler error:
**error C2071: foo::operator bool' : illegal storage class**

Comment: The code doesn't compile - there's your answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, VS2010 has a very limited C++0x support. Here is a [list of features that are supported by VS2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/04/06/c-0x-core-language-features-in-vc10-the-table.aspx).